# Can't run dnx web on osx

Tags: asp.net, macos, asp.net-core, dnx

It's about tutorial from http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html
When I run `dnx web` command on my OSX, I've an error `No service for type 'Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.IApplicationEnvironment' has been registered`
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you run `dnu restore`?

Comment: See this thread: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3066